# How to limit each user usage quota in amazon web services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have created users for my aws root account, is there any way to limit each user usage quota for each service.

for example-

- AWS IoT message quota for each user.
- EC2 instance type (allow only Free tier).

Thank you.

Comment: You can add a condition to IAM policies to limit the ec2 instance types users can start using the ec2:ImageType condition key.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_ec2.html

Answer (score 2):

EC2 instance type (allow only Free tier).

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
           "Effect": "Deny",
           "Action": "ec2:RunInstance",
           "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:regionname:Accountid:instance/*",
           "Condition": {
                "StringNotLike": {
                      "ec2:InstanceType": "t2.micro"
                }
           }
        }
    ]
}
```